# Xpath_get the text file from html page using xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I need to get the text, using the xpath below.
I have try to get to the appropriate text without success.

```
//*[@title="Vulnerability - level 5"]/child::[contains(text(),'RESULTS:')]/text()
```

[Photo to required text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoFhS.png)

Comment: it is better to show the code in text not in image it is not clear to understand...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your html file look like this:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div title="Vulnerability - level 5">
            <div>RESULTS: xyz xyz <a>abc</a></div>
        </div>
        <div title="Vulnerability - level 4">
            <div>RESULTS: xyz xyz</div>
        </div>

        <div title="Vulnerability - level 5">
            <div>xyz xyz RESULTS: xyz xyz</div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**XPath:**

```
//*[@title="Vulnerability - level 5"]/child::*[contains(.,'RESULTS:')]/string()
```

Please check this XPath hope it will help you to get your output.

Comment: The final `string()` function call makes this an XPath 2.0 expression.

Comment: Ohh yes you are right can replace `string()` to `text()` but it will return only first text.

Comment: You can use it like `string(//*[@title="Vulnerability - level 5"]/*[contains(.,'RESULTS:')])`